# How to use ColVis plugin in DT to hide multiple columns in a custom container?

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app wherein I am using the DT library to visualize a table. I am using a container to render the table.

```
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
class = 'display',
thead(
  tr(
    th(rowspan = 2, 'Name'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'Description'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'From'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'To'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'Duration'),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Rain', style="text-align:center"),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Flow', style="text-align:center"),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Depth', style="text-align:center"),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Velocity', style="text-align:center")
  ),
  tr(
    lapply(rep(c('Min', 'Max', 'Mean'), 4), th)
  )
)))
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(eventSelection[[input$options]], class = 'cell-border stripe table-hover', rownames = FALSE, container = sketch,
              extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(scrollX = TRUE, dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = I('colvis'))
              ) %>%
      formatDate(c(3,4), method='toLocaleString') %>%
      formatRound(5:17, digits = 3)
  })
```

The table looks like this:

[image: Shiny app table with Column Visibility options]

I want to have options Rain, Flow, Depth, Velocity in the column visibility tab and be able to hide the corresponding Min, Max and Mean statistics columns when I click on them. What would be the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by using datatables documentation.

Here's the code:

```
  sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
class = 'display',
thead(
  tr(
    th(rowspan = 2, 'Name'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'Description'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'From'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'To'),
    th(rowspan = 2, 'Duration'),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Rain', style="text-align:center"),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Flow', style="text-align:center"),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Depth', style="text-align:center"),
    th(colspan = 3, 'Velocity', style="text-align:center")
  ),
  tr(
    lapply(rep(c('Min', 'Max', 'Mean'), 4), th)
  )
)))



 button_list <- list(list(extend='colvisGroup', text="Rain", show=c(5:7)),
                      list(extend='colvisGroup', text="Flow", show=c(8:10)),
                      list(extend='colvisGroup', text="Depth", show=c(11:13)),
                      list(extend='colvisGroup', text="Velocity", show=c(14:16)),
                      list(extend='colvisGroup', text="Hide all", hide=c(5:16))
                      )

  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(eventSelection[[input$options]], class = 'cell-border stripe table-hover', rownames = FALSE, container = sketch,
              extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(scrollX = TRUE, dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                     columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(5:16))),
                                                     buttons = button_list)
              ) %>%
      formatDate(c(3,4), method='toLocaleString') %>%
      formatRound(5:17, digits = 3)
  })
```